# How to analyze event sequences with Apache Flink to trigger actions?

Tags: events, real-time, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to analyze event streams in real-time with Apache Flink and trigger actions based on:

- event windows, in which particular events occured ("if event A and event B occurred within 30 seconds -> trigger action")
- event sequences, in which particular events occurred ("if event A occurred after event B and event C occurred after event B -> trigger action")
- combinations of both

I know flink is capable of the windowing via `stream.windowAll(...)` but I am unsure how to reflect the event sequences.

How could such event sequence detections be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlinkCEP (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/libs/cep.html) is a CEP (Complex Event Processing) library capable of a more abstract way of processing streams of events and (among others) covers the scenarios you have described.

Comment: Great, didn't see it. Thanks!